# Print all PDF files in a directory with one click

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation, printing

On my desktop, I have a folder having many PDF files and a .bat file on desktop in which I have written a code to print all those files. However, as I double click on the bat file, it shows a window in which it opens all the pdf files, but not print them. So I want to further give it a command to print them.

This is my code:

```bash
@echo off
set "pdfFolder=C:\Path\To\Your\Folder"

for %%i in ("%pdfFolder%\*.pdf") do (
    echo Printing: %%i
    start /min /wait "" "%%i"
)

echo All PDFs printed.
```

Note: I am using Windows 11 64-bit and I not am **not** using Microsoft Edge as the pdf reader. I have also have set my printer as default printer.

Comment: Writing normal sentences, including titles, in all upper.case is considered as shouting. And it's very rude to should at the people you want to help you. Please [edit] your question to not shout at us.

Answer (score 0):

In order to program Windows native PDF Printing you need a programmable driver such as Selenium or Puppeteer or even native Windows Edge with VBS sendkeys. Personally since the last is supplied with the system, I will use an enhanced sendkeys.exe. However as I support SumatraPDF (one exe) PDF printing I would be using that anyway, but for efficiency always suggest use Personal Acrobat , or Commercial GhostScript PDF conversion to printers.

PDF printing requires Graphics Device Interface rendering into a printable form. Then a print driver such as supplied by Windows can programmatically convert the PDF screen drawing into printer programming language, such as PostScript or PDL or even PDF.

So you will need a batch or command file to interface with Edge application across its security boundary.

```
set "filename=%1"
rem use a seperate --profile-directory=Printer this will become "%userprofile%\%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Printer"
set "options=--pdf-upsell-disabled --enable-features=msAccessiblePDFFormRead,msPdfDigitalSignatureRead,msPdfSharedLibrary,msPdfVideoComment,msPdfXFA"
REM others usually automatically aded  --type=renderer --instant-process --pdf-upsell-enabled --lang=en-GB --js-flags=--ms-user-locale= --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=1 --renderer-client-id=22 --mojo-platform-channel-handle=6948 --field-trial-handle=2360,i,8200473590774869286,7624283130742998013,262144 --variations-seed-version /prefetch:1 Disabled

"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --no-first-run --profile-directory=Printer %options% --app="%filename%"
sendkeys blah blah
```

The above command script.bat will open MS Edge and wait for the sendkeys to drive the print dialogs.

[image]

To sendkeys via CScript you will need your programming skills and patience, while testing the all too many permutations. So here is the first part for you to build upon.
[image]

cscript print-filename.vbs

```
' Edge is already open waiting for commands

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep(100)

' we need to use the app name  which is the PDF name
WshShell.AppActivate("print-purchase_order.pdf")

' Give PDF time to become topmost
WScript.Sleep 500 

' Type in control P to trigger manual printing
WshShell.SendKeys "^P"

' Add more user specific key ins 
WshShell.SendKeys "Blah Blah"
```

Once the print is finished you will need to run a second close control

cscript close.vbs

```
' Edge is already open waiting for commands

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep(100)

' we need to use the app name  which is the current PDF name
WshShell.AppActivate("print-purchase_order.pdf")

' Finaly close Edge so the next one can run cleanly
WshShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"
```

Now you can wrap all those up in the for loop, basically this is emulating Adobe Reader /P command.